# what is the query after P&C?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a query

```
select sum(salary) 
from employees 
where email in ('BERNST','DAUSTIN','VPATABAL') 
and department_id in (90,60) 
and manager_id in (103,102);
```

So, I want to write the above query with the permutation combination of each IN's values like
the query should total of 12 queries. For example

```
select sum(salary) 
from employees 
where email = 'BERNST' 
and department_id = 90 
and manager_id = 103;

select sum(salary) 
from employees 
where email = 'BERNST'
and department_id = 90 
and manager_id = 102;

select sum(salary) 
from employees 
where email = 'BERNST'
and department_id = 60 
and manager_id = 103;

select sum(salary)  
from employees 
where email = 'BERNST'
and department_id = 60 
and manager_id = 102;

select sum(salary)  
from employees 
where email = 'BERNST'
and department_id = 90 
and manager_id = 103;
```

And so on.

How can I perform a P&C in a query to get 12 queries with each IN's values like above?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why do you want 12 queries? Why not have a single result using group by ?

Comment: Bcoz as per requirement if I use sum and all the combination of IN clauses it will give an only value which exists. If any of the IN clause value not present in the table then I won't throw any error bcoz another value exists.

Comment: Your reasoning is still not clear to me. It seems you have somehow assumed that generating 12 queries could be the only possible solution to your problem and focusing too much towards it in this question. Perhaps there is a much better solution to your original problem  which we are not aware of. So, it would greatly benefit you and others here if you could tell us what you want to accomplish ultimately, to get an efficient solution rather than going down the rabbit hole.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe something like this:

```
with
  emails as  
  (
     select 'BERNST'  as email  from dual union
     select 'DAUSTIN'  from dual union
     select 'VPATABAL' from dual 
  )
, departments as
  (
     select 90 department_id from dual union
     select 60 from dual
  )
, managers as
  (
     select 103 as manager_id from dual union
     select 102 from dual
  )
select 
  'select sum(salary) from employees where email = '''
  || E.email ||
  ''' and department_id = '
  || D.department_id ||
  ' and manager_id = '
  || M.manager_id ||
  ' ;' 
  as query_
from emails E, departments D, managers M 
;
```

Output:

```
QUERY_                                                                                                                     
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
select sum(salary) from employees where email = 'BERNST' and department_id = 60 and manager_id = 102 ;                     
select sum(salary) from employees where email = 'DAUSTIN' and department_id = 60 and manager_id = 102 ;                    
select sum(salary) from employees where email = 'VPATABAL' and department_id = 60 and manager_id = 102 ;                   
select sum(salary) from employees where email = 'BERNST' and department_id = 60 and manager_id = 103 ;                     
select sum(salary) from employees where email = 'DAUSTIN' and department_id = 60 and manager_id = 103 ;                    
select sum(salary) from employees where email = 'VPATABAL' and department_id = 60 and manager_id = 103 ;                   
select sum(salary) from employees where email = 'BERNST' and department_id = 90 and manager_id = 102 ;                     
select sum(salary) from employees where email = 'DAUSTIN' and department_id = 90 and manager_id = 102 ;                    
select sum(salary) from employees where email = 'VPATABAL' and department_id = 90 and manager_id = 102 ;                   
select sum(salary) from employees where email = 'BERNST' and department_id = 90 and manager_id = 103 ;                     
select sum(salary) from employees where email = 'DAUSTIN' and department_id = 90 and manager_id = 103 ;                    
select sum(salary) from employees where email = 'VPATABAL' and department_id = 90 and manager_id = 103 ;                   

12 rows selected.
```

See also: [dbfiddle here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=9effdd0eae75b84320d16c2c70093a18).
(No idea what "P&C" stands for ...)

**PL/SQL** code (as requested)

Assumption: the "employees" table contains the columns email, department_id, and manager_id.  We SELECT DISTINCT values, and use cross joins to get all required combinations.  You can also pass the table name and the column names as parameters if need be.

```
create or replace package generate_sql
is
  procedure print_queries ;
end;
/

create or replace package body generate_sql
is
  procedure print_queries
  is
    selectstr constant varchar2(128) :=  'select sum(salary) from employees where email = ''' ;
    andstr1   constant varchar2(128) :=  ''' and department_id = ' ;
    andstr2   constant varchar2(128) :=  ' and manager_id = ' ;
  begin
    for rec_ in (
      select *
      from (
        select distinct email 
        from employees
      ), (
        select distinct department_id
        from employees
      ), ( 
        select distinct manager_id
        from employees
      )
    ) loop
      dbms_output.put_line( 
           selectstr || rec_.email 
        || andstr1   || rec_.department_id
        || andstr2   || rec_.manager_id || ' ;' 
      ) ;
    end loop;
  end print_queries;
end generate_sql;
/
```

Execute

```
begin
  generate_sql.print_queries ;
end;
/
```

**Tests** ( results see dbfiddle )

For collecting the generated SQL statements (dbms_output.put_line is no use in dbfiddle):

```
create table generated_queries ( varchar2(4000) ) ;


-- 3 email addresses, 2 departments, 2 managers -> 12 queries
create table employees as
select 'BERNST' email, 60 department_id, 102 manager_id from dual union all
select 'DAUSTIN' , 90, 103 from dual union all
select 'VPATABAL', 60, 103 from dual
;

-- 4 email addresses, 4 departments, 2 managers -> 32 queries
-- drop table employees;

create table employees as
select 'BERNST' email, 10 department_id, 102 manager_id from dual union all
select 'DAUSTIN' , 20, 103 from dual union all
select 'VPATABAL', 30, 103 from dual union all
select 'SSRIVASTAVA', 40, 102 from dual
;
```

See dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=73fd9cf179c536b6a6cdb554c33625a1).

For some of us (including myself) it is still not quite clear what you want to do with all these queries (no need to tell us, though :-)).  Trusting that you are aware of what can be done with GROUP BY / ROLLUP / CUBE etc: best of luck!

Comment: "P & C" would be "permutation & combination", I presume.

Comment: Yes,P&C is permutation and combination.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying!  Is this the query you were after?  Or did you strictly want PL/SQL code?

Comment: For your query, as I can see that you have hardcoded the queries. I have a procedure where the queries are generating and I can't say that these values are coming every time i run the code. Sometimes, there are 4 IN clause are there sometimes 3. So I can't use the above code. If you have any other solution apart from hardcode, plz let me know. Need a PLSQL code.

Answer (score 1):

I don't find dynamic construction of 12 queries to be particularly useful.

If you want the actual *results*, then use `cross join` to get the rows and `left join` and aggregation to get the final sums:

```
with emails as(
      select 'BERNST'  as email  from dual union
      select 'DAUSTIN'  from dual union
      select 'VPATABAL' from dual 
     ),
     departments as (
      select 90 department_id from dual union
      select 60 from dual
     ),
     managers as (
      select 103 as manager_id from dual union
      select 102 from dual
     )
select e.email, d.department_id, m.manager_id, sum(emp.salary)
from emails e cross join
     departments d cross join
     managers m left join
     employees emp
     on emp.email = e.email and emp.department_id = d.department_id and
        emp.manager_id = m.manager_id
group by e.email, d.department_id, m.manager_id;
```